# Changing list to tuple

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I have the following function:

```
range[n_] := 
 Flatten[Table[{Subscript[v, i], -Infinity, Infinity}, {i, 1, 
    n}, {v, {x, y}}], 1]
```

For example, `range[2]` gives the following result:

```
{{Subscript[x, 1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[y, 
  1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[x, 
  2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[y, 
  2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}}
```

The purpose of my function is to use it in the `NIntegrate` command as,

```
NIntegrate[integrand, range[2]]
```

where I hope `range[2]` automatically changes to:

```
{Subscript[x, 1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[y, 
      1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[x, 
      2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[y, 
      2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}
```

so that the whole `NIntegrate` works. However, my function `range[n]` produces additional outermost braces. How can I remove this brace, so that I can put `range[n]` inside `NIntegrate`?

Comment: In `Flatten` what you are after? To remove the outer brackets I mean. Can you try `range[2] // Flatten`

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 That gives
`{Subscript[x, 1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity], Subscript[y, 1], -\
\[Infinity], \[Infinity], Subscript[x, 2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity], \
Subscript[y, 2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}`
which is not what I want. I want to remove the "outer" brace, but `Flatten` removes the "inner" brace.

Comment: Please include a sample integrand that works with your current notation i.e., when entered manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. You need to infuse the range[2] using `Sequence` like e.g.:

```
Integrate[1, Sequence @@ range[2]]
```

[image]

Of course this example does not converge.

Comment: Thanks for your simple answer!

Comment: Interestingly, if I change `Integrate` to `NIntegrate`, there is an error:

`NIntegrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in HoldForm[{Subscript[x, 1],-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},{Subscript[y, 1],-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}].`

However, if I change to `Evaluate[Sequence @@ range[2]]`, it works!

Comment: The trouble comes from "NIntegrate" having the attribute "HoldAll". This prevent the Sequence command to be  evaluated. To circumvent this, try e.g. : `nintegrate[x_, y__] := NIntegrate[x, y]
nintegrate[Exp[-x1^2 - y1^2], Sequence @@ range[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

I will change the infinities to some finite values, in order to get nice results.

```
range[n_] := 
 Flatten[Table[{Subscript[v, i], -10, 10}, {i, 1, n}, {v, {x, y}}], 1]
```

Then you can pick up $x_1$ as follows:

```
a = (range[2])[[1]]
```

And use it in `NIntegrate`

Likewise for the other variables. If you have say, two variables, you can proceed similarly. Below is an example with $x_1$ and $y_1$

```
a1 = (range[2])[[1]]
a2 = (range[2])[[2]]
```

And then you can evaluate

```
NIntegrate[Subscript[x, 1]^2 + Subscript[y, 1], a1, a2]
```

And I think it should be clear how to go about it.
Is this what you were looking for?